# How to set up VueJS routes and NodeJS Express API routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

API routes return always `HTML` never `JSON` - I have tried a lot of different solutions but none of them worked.

Here is the current setup:

```js
// server.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const history = require("connect-history-api-fallback");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(cors());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require("./routes")(app);

app.use(history());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist")));
app.get(`/`, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist", "index.html"));
});



// routes.js
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get(`/user`, async (req, res){
    // Also, I have tested with res.json AND setting the content type manually
    return res.send({ test: 123 });
  });
}
```

**The problem:**
Hitting `/user` endpoint will always return the `index.html` file, no matter what.

What I'm missing?

**Btw, works great on local, not on production. Can be something to do with the Nginx config?**

```js
// Nginx configs

server {
    root /var/www/example.com/client/dist;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: By removing the route for SPA the API endpoint throws `Cannot GET /index.html`

Comment: If someone has the same issue you can read my solution I post to my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400547/nodejs-express-api-only-returns-index-html-file-on-production/62402140#62402140

Answer (score 0):

A one-page website like VueJS handles all the pages client-side. `index.html` contains all the pages you need configured in your vuejs router. The page shown depends on the url in your address bar.

To fix your code all the request should return a static file from `dist`if it exists and for all other requests return `index.html`.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist")));
app.get((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: There's no problem serving files, but hitting the `API` endpoints. API should not return `index.html` file

Comment: If someone has the same issue you can read my solution I post to my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400547/nodejs-express-api-only-returns-index-html-file-on-production/62402140#62402140