# NodeJS Express API only returns index.html file on production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My original question: [How to set up VueJS routes and NodeJS Express API routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391953/how-to-set-up-vuejs-routes-and-nodejs-express-api-routes)

I got feedback that if [Serving VueJS Builds via Express.js using history mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327143/serving-vuejs-builds-via-express-js-using-history-mode) question doesn't solve my issue, I need to ask a new question, so here I'm.

**Problem:**
NodeJS (powered by express) API return always `index.html` - no matter what.

**Notes**
- Works great on local
- API returns the `index.html` file only on production

I'm super confused what can cause this?

I place my Nginx configs in here as well, since I think it has something to do my production server since the issue only happens there:

```js
server {
    root /var/www/example.com/client/dist;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

NodeJS server:

```js
// server.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const history = require("connect-history-api-fallback");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(cors());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get(`/user`, async (req, res){
  // Also, I have tested with res.json AND setting the content type manually
  return res.send({ test: 123 });
});

app.use(history());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist")));
app.get(`/`, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/dist", "index.html"));
});

server.listen(1234);
```

**Problem:**
NodeJS (powered by express) API return always `index.html` - no matter what.

Comment: I have build the api with nodejs Typescript. Now when i am deployed the api to shared hosting. mines one also trying to find the index.html, no matter what's endpoint i am calling.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing all `API` endpoints under `/api` prefix and changed the Nginx configs to be something like this:

```js
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

So, now using `/api/user` instead of `/user` works as expected. Doesn't return the `index.html` file anymore.